# Fetch jquery ajax call into array

Tags: jquery, ajax

I would like to know if it is possible to return the ajax call into a javascript array, rather than a DOM object. The ajax call is returning something like n-tuples of value1-value2, and I would like to iterate over that.

Thanks.

```
$(function () {
    $("#categoria").change(function() {
        var id = $(this).val();
        alert(id);
        vars = load("getcategoria.php", "q="+id); // can I do something like this? how?
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can do this, but [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load) is the wrong method for the job.  [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load) is used to load HTML into a specific DOM element.

I suggest you have your `getcategoria.php` return a JSON object (use PHP's [`json_encode`](http://php.net/json_encode)), and then use [`$.getJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) to get it, parse it, and use it how you wish.

```
$.getJSON("getcategoria.php", "q="+id, function(data){
  // data is your JSON object, use it how you wish
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jQuery [getJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) method to return a JSON String which you can then iterate over.

This example from the linked page shows how on retrieving a JSON string you then iterate over it and generate a list. YOu can modify this to perform your own iteration and behaviour.

```
  $.getJSON('ajax/test.json', function(data) {
  var items = [];

 $.each(data, function(key, val) {
   items.push('<li id="' + key + '">' + val + '</li>');
 });

  $('<ul/>', {
   'class': 'my-new-list',
   html: items.join('')
  }).appendTo('body');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

And dont forget to have set `header('content-type: application/json')` in your getcategoria.php file